# Calling Method on Generic Type Java 8

Tags: java, function, generics

I have a `function` that accepts a parameter that has some `generic` type

> public < T extends SomeA > String foo(T t) {...}

Now... `SomeA` contains a series of methods that can be called, like `baz1()`, `baz2()`, `baz3()`, etc...

Now, here's the rub

1. The variable `T` that will be passed into `foo(T t)` will be an instance of either `SomeB` or `SomeC`, where `SomeB extends SomeA` and `SomeC extends someA`.
2. Both `SomeB` and `SomeC` contains a method `glop(...)` which returns `SomeD`, *however*, `glop(...)` is not in `SomeA`.
3. I want to be able to pass `foo(T t)` around so that it accepts either `SomeB` or `SomeC`, however, I need to call `glop(...)` (e.g follows)

E.g.

```
public < T extends SomeA > String foo(T t) {
    return t.glop().methodInsideOfSomeD().toString();
}
```

I would rather not implement `foo` separately for `SomeB` and `SomeC` (i.e. `fooSomeB` `fooSomeC`). I want to be able to pass this method around to functions providing either `SomeB` or `SomeC` (or even better anything that contains the method `glop(...)`).

The *problem*: I do not have the ability to change the implementation or declaration of `SomeB` or `SomeC` since they reside in libraries I do not control. Thus, I cannot have them both implement some interface that provides `glop(...)`.

Am I just out of luck?

Comment: Can you add `glop` to `SomeA`?

Comment: Or, can you create an interface `CanGlop` with a default implementation of `glop()` and have `SomeB` and `SomeC` implement `CanGlop` as well as derive from `SomeA`?

Comment: Yes, you're out of luck. Either create two methods, or make an interface Glopable, and create adapter classes that implement Glopable by delegating to a SomeB or a SomeC.

Comment: I cannot touch `SomeA`, `SomeB`, or `SomeC`. They exist in another library that I have no control over. So in my project, I'm literally just grabbing a `SomeB` or `SomeC`, and in their library they are extensions of `SomeA`. I don't believe I can change `SomeA`, `SomeB`, or `SomeC` unless I can touch their source, can I?

Comment: You're basically out of luck. However depending on the circumstance you might be able to solve your problem using a facade: make an interface `Wrapper` that exposes all the methods you need from `SomeA` as well as `glop()` and then make two implementations, one that takes a `SomeB` on the constructor and delegates all calls to it, and another that does the same for `SomeC`. Then when you get a `SomeB` or `SomeC`, wrap it with the appropriate wrapper, after which you can write code in terms of `Wrapper`.

Comment: Why not did you try a captcha?

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is pretty much no point to defining a generic method with the signature you describe.  If the type parameter `T` is used only as the type of one or more arguments, then you might as well simplify things by manually erasing it:

```
public String foo(SomeA t) { /* ... */ }
```

---

In any case, you have at least these alternatives consistent with your requirements:

1. Replace the one `foo()` with two overloaded ones, one whose type parameter is bounded by `SomeB`, and another whose type parameter is bounded by `SomeC`.  This assumes that you have no other subtypes of `SomeA` to worry about for this purpose, which seems reasonable given that `SomeA` doesn't have `glop()`.
2. In the implementation of `foo()`, use the `instanceof` operator (or `Class.isInstance()`) to recognize instances of `SomeB` and `SomeC`, and handle them appropriately.
3. Use reflection in `foo()` to determine whether the argument's class provides an accessible `glop()` having the expected signature, and if so, invoke it reflectively.

None of these require you to modify `SomeA`, `SomeB`, or `SomeC` in any way.  I know you said you don't want to do (1), but it's pretty clean and easy.  You should consider it.

> I want to be able to pass this method around to functions providing [...] or even better anything that contains the method glop(...)).

That would be (3), maybe with the argument type changed to `Object`, but I'm doubtful that you really want that.  Reflection is messy, and usually it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood, you will have to duplicate the method, but you may reuse the code by factorizing the common parts:

```
public < T extends SomeB > String foo(T t) {return fooX(t.glop());}
public < T extends SomeC > String foo(T t) {return fooX(t.glop());}
```

And a new method taking the result of `glop()`:

```
private String fooX(SomeD globResult) {
  return globResult.methodInsideOfSomeD().toString();
}
```

I don't know why you can't change `SomeA` to add that `glob()` method with a default implementation (or method), but if you can add an interface to your `SomeB`/`SomeC` class, say `ProviderOfSomeD`, you can do that:

```
public < T extends SomeA & ProviderOfSomeD> String foo(T t) {return fooX(t.glop());}
```

Notice there is a limit to what you can do with that.

Another Java 8 way (does not require any change):

```
public String foo(final Supplier<? extends SomeD> t) {return fooX(t.get());}

// calling them:
SomeB b = ...;
SomeC b = ...;
foo(b::glop);
foo(c::glop);
```