# How to call get method of a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, methods

**How can I tell the compiler that I am sure that this generic type has the method get?**

I have done a little bit of research, and let the T extends some interface might help. 
[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578547/10189759)
[example2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47b8da24-754f-4dac-9b57-b57e012a73ba/it-is-possible-to-call-a-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter?forum=csharplanguage)

1. But what is the exact interface I have to extends for the method **get**?
2. **How could I search for this interface in IDE?**  So that next time, I could avoid asking if it is some methods other than **get**

   ```
   private static <T> ArrayList<T> trimstartend(ArrayList<T> rows,Date startdate ,Date endDate){

   // if the date of current row is before the startdate, remove it
   for (Iterator<T> iterator = rows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
       T row = iterator.next();
       if ((Date)row.get("Date").before(startdate) ) {    // this line doesn't compile!  Unresolved method get 
           iterator.remove();
       }
   }

   // if the date of current row is after the enddate, remove it
   for (Iterator<T> iterator = rows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
       T row = iterator.next();
       if ((Date)row.get("Date").after(endDate)) {        // this line doesn't compile!   Unresolved method get
           iterator.remove();
       }
   }

   return rows;
   }
   ```

**Actually T is hashmap.  But let us make it generic here.**

Comment: `HashMap` implements the `Map` interface. This interface contains the `get` method. You could write `T extends Map<…, …>` or just `? extends Map<…, …>`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Your answer inspires me that I can directly `<T extends HashMap<...,...> >`    I just want the get method, so both works, right?

Comment: Well, first, you should then use `Map` instead of `HashMap`, this is called [to program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). Second, you cannot just "cherry pick" a single method (e.g. `get`) to be implemented in some type; instead, you define the type which contains the method.

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you want to achieve, and why you want to use generics at all.

Comment: Oh, and note that the `Date` class is obsolete; you should instead use classes from the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices:

1. Use an interface such as `Map` which has the `get()` method. This however would limit `T` to be a `Map` and not anything with a `get` method.
2. Use a custom interface that has the `get()` method, but since Java doesn't have [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), you'd need to extend the `HashMap` so it'll implement the custom interface, which isn't very convenient, especially if you're getting the `HashMap` from elsewhere.
3. Finally, you could have the user to supply a function as a parameter. Maybe something like `Function<String, Date>`. For a `HashMap`, it will simply be the `get()` method for `HashMap`, but for other data types, it can be something else.

   Your function would be something like:
   `private static <T> ArrayList<T> trimstartend(ArrayList<T> rows,Date startdate ,Date endDate, Function<String, Date> dateGetter)`

   And to get the `Date` using the `String`, you'd have to call `dateGetter.apply("Date")`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface (e. g. `Gettable`), and write `T extends Gettable`.

OK, as `@Malt` points out, if a class doesn't implement this interface, extend it so that the new class does:

```
public interface Gettable {
    Object get(String key);
}
public class GettableHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Gettable {
    @Override
    public Object get(String key) {
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only `HashMap` is not going to implement `Gettable` by itself...

Comment: @Malt You can create a subclass of HashMap that implements it

Comment: Yes. That's why it should be in the answer.

Comment: sorry ,  so I should write  `<T extends Gettable>`   or `<T extends GettableHashMap> `

Comment: @Luk Aron <T extends Gettable>. But instead of HashMap use GettableHashMap.